# Formatting Text Color In JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtextarea

I'm redirecting the Java console output to a JTextArea that is inside of a JPanel.  I'm using  `System.out.setOut(new PrintStream(taOutputStream))` and `System.out.setErr(new PrintStream(taOutputStream))`for redirecting the output.

The problem I'm running into that the text is always black when it's redirected to the JPanel. I want the setErr code to be red like normal. I tried creating a method for the setErr to change the text to red, but it ends up applying it to all of the text instead.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to implement this so the error code is red, and the standard out is black?

Here are the classes I have, as well as a screenshot of the JPanel output.

TextAreaOutputStream class

```
package application;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TextAreaOutputStream extends OutputStream
{
    private final JTextArea textArea;
    private final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    public TextAreaOutputStream(final JTextArea textArea)
    {
        this.textArea = textArea;
        //this.title = title;
        sb.append(">>> ");
    }

    @Override
    public void flush()
    {}

    @Override
    public void close()
    {}

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException 
    {

        if (b == '\r')
            return;

        if (b == '\n') 
        {
            final String text = sb.toString() + "\n";
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run() 
                {
                    textArea.append(text);
                }
            });
            sb.setLength(0);
            sb.append(">>> ");
        }

        sb.append((char) b);
    }

    public TextAreaOutputStream setTextColor(TextAreaOutputStream textArea)
    {
        this.textArea.setForeground(Color.red);

        return textArea;
    }
}
```

TextAreaOutputStreamTest Class

```
package application;
![enter image description here][1]
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TextAreaOutputStreamTest extends JPanel
{

   private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(15, 75);
   private TextAreaOutputStream taOutputStream = new TextAreaOutputStream(
         textArea);

   public TextAreaOutputStreamTest() 
   {
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(new JScrollPane(textArea, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, 
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS));
      System.setOut(new PrintStream(taOutputStream));
      System.setErr(new PrintStream(taOutputStream.setTextColor(taOutputStream)));
   }

   public static void createAndShowGui() 
   {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Java Console Output");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new TextAreaOutputStreamTest());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Screenshot of JPanel output:

[image]

Comment: JTextarea only supports 1 color and 1 font for text. If you want multiple text styles, you should use JTextPane

Comment: Ah, thanks! I should ControlAltDel myself after that one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `JTextPane` for multiple colors.

Check out the [Message Console](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/message-console/) which allows you to redirect messages to the text pane. You can also control the text color for the "err" and "out" messages.

Comment: I have a question for you, when using the JTextArea all of the console text was appended to the text area. When I was trying to implement the JTextPane, it would only display the current line. The previous lines disappeared or whatever happened to them. For the JTextPane I was using the .setText(text) method which was obviously the problem. However, I was unable to find an append? Do you have any suggestions to append the text?

Comment: You miss the point of the `Message Console`. You don't add text to it manually. You redirect System.out. and System.err output to the text area and it will insert the text into the Document for you. However as a general answer to your question all text components use a Document. Text is added to the Document by using the insertString(..) method of the Document.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using just:

`System.err.println("Error String:");`

Instead of:

```
System.setErr(new PrintStream(taOutputStream.setTextColor(taOutputStream)));
```